# FMX: TMenuItem shortcuts Ctrl+Alt+O and Ctrl+Alt+A don't work

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Setting a TMenuItem Shortcut to Ctrl+Alt+O or Ctrl+Alt+A results in these items not triggering the event when using those shortcuts. However, Ctrl+Alt+B and most others do work. I have not tested all combinations to see which ones work and which ones don't.

Run the application below and press Ctrl+Alt+A. The Label should show 'MenuItem2 clicked', but nothing happens. Press Ctrl+Alt+B and the label shows 'MenuItem3 clicked' as expected.

I have already raised the issue [here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34296). My question is if anyone knows a workaround? I have tried detecting the keypresses in the form's OnKeyDown event, but this doesn't seem to work either. I suspect that this has something to do with typing special characters in Windows. Doing Ctrl+Alt+A in Notepad produces a 'á' while Ctrl+Alt+O produces 'ó'. If I set my Windows language to French then Ctrl+Alt+O now works in the application, but Ctrl+Alt+A still doesn't.

Note that, VCL applications with menu items with these shortcuts always work fine.

Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 265
  ClientWidth = 355
  Position = ScreenCenter
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnKeyDown = FormKeyDown
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 96.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label1'
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
    object MenuItem4: TMenuItem
      Text = 'Menu'
      object MenuItem1: TMenuItem
        Locked = True
        ShortCut = 49231
        Text = 'MenuItem1'
        OnClick = MenuItem1Click
      end
      object MenuItem2: TMenuItem
        Locked = True
        ShortCut = 49217
        Text = 'MenuItem2'
        OnClick = MenuItem2Click
      end
      object MenuItem3: TMenuItem
        Locked = True
        ShortCut = 49218
        Text = 'MenuItem3'
        OnClick = MenuItem3Click
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    Label1: TLabel;
    MenuItem2: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem3: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem4: TMenuItem;
    procedure MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'MenuItem1 Clicked';
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'MenuItem2 Clicked';
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'MenuItem3 Clicked';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Caption := KeyChar + ' , ' + Chr(Key); // Debug
  // Below code doesn't work either
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (ssAlt in Shift) and (KeyChar = 'A') then
    MenuItem2Click(Self);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Ctrl+Alt (also known as AltGr) is used for typing language-specific characters. You can't use them as hotkeys if the keyboard layout uses them.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Thanks, but how do you explain my VCL application (Delphi 7) not having the same issue? Those hotkeys work fine.

Comment: I cannot explain. Maybe VCL is doing something funny and bypassing normal language processing (which is a bad idea - what if you wanted to type a "á"?)

Comment: OK then, thanks for the answer. Delphi shouldn't really allow it as a shortcut option then.

Comment: But then you'd have complaints from users saying "I can guarantee that I'm using a US-English keyboard layout that doesn't use Ctrl+Alt for anything special, why are you stopping me from doing this perfectly legitimate thing?" I can see them allowing it but putting up a warning "This hotkey combination may not work in all keyboard layouts."

Comment: These shortcuts are used in many other Windows applications and they work fine. For example Inkscape uses Ctrl+Alt+A for selecting all objects in all layers. There doesn't seem to be any conflict other than in FMX applications.